# Traditional For Loop for simple VF page

Tags: visualforce

I have a hopefully simple question that I'm stuck on.  I'm trying to introduce a simple for loop (or similar functionality) in a VF page for some apex field outputs.  We're wanting to print X number of product labels for some warehouse barcoding. I have it working without the for loop callout (just prints 2 labels), but when I introduce the for loop, i'm getting the below syntax error. I haven't been able to find any similar examples so I'm wondering if it's possible like this.

Error

> Error: BarCodeVF2 line 5, column 24: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup
>   Error   Error: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.

A few notes.

- We're on professional edition, so I don't think we can use apex classes as part of solution.
- I'm looking at trying to use something very simple like this traditional for loop, but perhaps pass in a number input field (Number_of_Barcodes__c) in place of the 10 threshold limit (so i < Number_of_Barcodes__c)- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_traditional.htm

here's the VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Product2" standardStylesheets="false">

<div id="InnternalDiv" style="width:250px;"> 

for (Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

<apex:outputfield value="{!Product2.Barcode__c}"/>
<br></br>
<apex:outputText value="AX Part Number: " escape="false"/><apex:outputText value="{!Product2.Productcode}" escape="false"/>
<br></br>
<apex:outputText value="Manufacturer: " escape="false"/><apex:outputText value="{!Product2.Manufacturer__c}" escape="false"/>        
<br></br>
<apex:outputText value="Model Number: " escape="false"/><apex:outputText value="{!Product2.Model_Number__c}" escape="false"/>
<br></br>
<apex:outputText value="" escape="false"/>
<br></br>
<apex:outputfield value="{!Product2.Barcode__c}"/>
<br></br>
<apex:outputText value="AX Part Number: " escape="false"/><apex:outputText value="{!Product2.Productcode}" escape="false"/>
<br></br>
<apex:outputText value="Manufacturer: " escape="false"/><apex:outputText value="{!Product2.Manufacturer__c}" escape="false"/>
<br></br>
<apex:outputText value="Model Number: " escape="false"/><apex:outputText value="{!Product2.Model_Number__c}" escape="false"/>    

}

    </div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You'd have to do this in JavaScript, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

An apex loop will not help you here although if you ever need a loop in VF, you need to use the `<script>` label to do the loop in javascript.

Because your class has a standardController you only have one record to work with - you should look into StandardSetController here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm

With this you can use markup such as `<apex:repeat>`

Comment: Thanks Glen.  any examples that show how I can use an apex field output within a javascript loop inside a visualforce page?  I'm currently trying, and it's saving the VF page without issue, but i'm not seeing any content returned for the javascript loop.

Comment: Here's what i'm trying within the apex page <script>
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";

<apex:outputText value="test" escape="false"/>

}
</script>

Comment: Don't specify a value in the outputText since it is dynamic. Give the outputText an id so you can later apply the value when the for loop finishes running. Applying the value would be something like document.getElementById(someID).value(text);